# How add comment if the cell is not previously empty?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add auto comment log code to the cells that are changed.

I want to add a comment only if the cell was not empty, I mean if the cell already has a content.

My code is adding a comment to every cell even if it is the first time that I am writing something to the new cell.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim singlecell As Range

If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 100000 Then Exit Sub

For Each singlecell In Target

    If singlecell.Comment Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
        singlecell.AddComment Now & " - " _
          & "new value: " _
          & singlecell.Value & " - " _
          & Environ("username") & " -" _
          & "changed the value from a NULL value."

    ElseIf Not singlecell.Comment Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Target.Comment.Text _
          vbNewLine & Now & " - " _
          & "value changed to: " _
          & Target.Value & " - by: " _
          & Environ("username") & " -" _
          , Len(Target.Comment.Text) + 1 _
          , False

    ElseIf singlecell.Comment Is Nothing And Target.Value = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    
    End If

    singlecell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
   
Next singlecell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found my own answer 
the below code works and only adding comments if the cell is not empty. so its making this easy to track changes made to any cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then
Exit Sub
Else
If Target.Comment Is Nothing And Target.CountLarge < 2 Then

Target.AddComment Now & " - " _
& "prev value = " _
& ActiveCell.Value & " - " _
& "new value: " _
& Target.Value & " - " _
& Environ("username") & " -" _
& "changed the value from a NULL value."

ElseIf Not Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
Target.Comment.Text _
vbNewLine & Now & " - " _
& "value changed to: " _
& Target.Value & " - by: " _
& Environ("username") & " -" _
, Len(Target.Comment.Text) + 1 _
, False

Exit Sub


End If

End If
If Target.CountLarge < 2 Then
 Target.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
 End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    On Error Resume Next
    S_Cell.AddComment
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        S_Cell.Comment.Delete
        S_Cell.AddComment
    End If
```